# How to export a xlsx file written with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, django

I have written some data in xlxs file with help of xlsxwriter I want to export it so that it can be downloaded how is this possible

```
def export(request,pk):
    import xlsxwriter

    product_resources = ProductType.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print(product_resources)
    attr = product_resources.product_attributes.all()
    r1=[]

    r1.append(str(product_resources))
    for i in range(0,len(attr)):
        r1.append(str(attr[i]))
    print(r1)
    if(request.GET):
        col=0
        row=0
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Product.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        for item in r1:
            worksheet.write_string(row,col, item)
            col+=1


        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="product.xlsx"'
        workbook.close()

        return response
```

This is my method but I am getting a file which is empty and could not be opened

Answer (score 1):

```
response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=product.xlsx"
```

Just try this.

content-type you have used is for xls files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this instead of your code.

```
def export(request,pk):
    import xlsxwriter

    output = io.BytesIO()

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output,{'in_memory': True})
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'remove_timezone': True})

    product_resources = ProductType.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print(product_resources)
    attr = product_resources.product_attributes.all()
    r1=[]

    r1.append(str(product_resources))
    for i in range(0,len(attr)):
        r1.append(str(attr[i]))
    print(r1)
    if(request.GET):
        col=0
        row=0

        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        for item in r1:
            worksheet.write_string(row,col, item)
            col+=1

        output.seek(0)

        response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=product.xlsx"
        workbook.close()

        return response
```